# How to solve an ODE where the rate is directly proportional to two amounts?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, applications, chemistry

> Two chemicals in solution react together to form a compound: one unit of compound is formed from $a$ units of chemical $A$ and $b$ units of chemical $B$, with $a + b = 1$.   Assume the concentration is low enough that the rate of reaction is directly proportional to the amount of chemical $A$ present, and directly proportional to the amount of chemical $B$ present.  For example, doubling the amount of $A$ and tripling the amount of $B$ would increase the rate of reaction by a factor of 6.
>
> Find the amount produced $x$ after $t$ seconds, up to a constant of proportionality.

I attempted to solve this using differential equations, but got a nonsensical result.  Can you help me find my error?

*(These [other math.SE posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705666/chemical-reactions-and-law-of-masses) are [relevant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1777560/integral-of-dfrac1x-ax-b-when-a-b-are-both-different-and-the-same) but didn't answer my question.)*

---

Let $A_0$ be the initial amount of chemical $A$ and $B_0$ of $B$.  Define $$\alpha = \frac {A_0}{a} \\ \beta = \frac {B_0} {b}.$$  Then the rate of change of the amount of the compound $x$ is $$\begin{align*}
\frac {dx} {dt} &= k(a\alpha -ax)(b\beta -bx) \\
&= kab(x - \alpha)(x - \beta).
\end{align*}$$

Therefore, $$t = \frac {1} {kab} \int \frac {1}{(x -\alpha)(x - \beta) }\, dx.$$

First, consider the case of $\alpha = \beta$ (that is, the two reactants are in ideal proportion).  Then $$t = \frac {1}{kab}\frac {1}{\alpha - x} + C \\
x = \alpha - \frac {1}{kabt} + C$$ with $C$ capturing the initial amount of product (presumably zero).

As expected, as $t \to \infty, x \to \alpha + C.$  But this solution also claims that as $t \to 0, x \to - \infty$, which is of course impossible!

Where is my error?

Comment: There is a mistake when you derive the equation from $x$ from the equation for $t$. The $+C$ should be subtracted from $t$. Then, if you compute $C$ explicitly, it should give you the correct formula (with, I guess, x(0)=0).

Comment: Yes, but you need to add *some* constant to t in the denominator, that is my point

Comment: your ODE is autonomous. Given a solution, translating $t$ by any constant gives another solution. Drawing a graph with $t$  the horizontal axis  and $x(t)$  shown vertically, the effect is to shift the graph left or right. Put another way: in calculations, you may introduce a constant $C,$  but it stays with the $t$  always

Comment: Meanwhile, when $\alpha \neq \beta,$  there are two constant solutions. And three sorts of nonconstant:  $x$ bigger than both $\alpha, \beta,$  or $x$ less than both, finally $x$  in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start from

$$t = \frac {1}{kab}\frac {1}{\alpha - x} + C, $$
you get

$$ x = \alpha - \frac {1}{kab(t-C)}.$$

Then, I am sure that if you compute $C$ explicitly, you find that it’s negative, so that the fraction does not blow up at $t=0$ or any positive time.

Comment: Thank you.  Using this, I get $x = \alpha (1 - \frac {1} {\alpha k a b t + 1})$.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it sounds correct. At t=0 yields x=0, and it gives $\alpha$ as $t\to+\infty$, which is good since in the case $\alpha=\beta$, one also has $\alpha=A_0+B_0$.